# How to recreate from childFragmentManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, child-fragment

I am using a custom layout for my settings Fragment like this

```
class SettingsFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private var settings: FragmentSettingsBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateBaseView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        parent: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        settings = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, true)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        childFragmentManager.apply {
            popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
            beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.settings, Settings())
                commit()
            }
        }
    }

    open class Settings :
        PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
           
            // recreate after some actions
       }
   }
}
```

Everything works fins until it come to `recreate` and than happens this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 16108
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.myapp.fragments.SettingsFragment$Settings: could not find Fragment constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4031)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4197)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:6334)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:6199)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:65)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:6288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2444)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.myapp.fragments.SettingsFragment$Settings: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:630)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$2.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:448)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:81)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveStateInternal(FragmentManager.java:2410)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1934)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1911)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2773)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1935)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1911)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2773)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:252)
        at com.example.myapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8282)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4005)
            ... 17 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.myapp.fragments.SettingsFragment$Settings.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1759)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:615)
            ... 48 more
```

I searched for similar cases and unfortunately, did not find any suitable solution.

I use one single `MainActivity` with a `FragmentContainerView` on it. There is one `BaseFragment` with a custom layout and that layout owns my Settings as child `Fragment`.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Try to create a no-arg constructor in the `Settings` fragment

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I had some arguments in `Settings` class and I removed them. Now it works.

Comment: Which `PreferenceFragmentCompat` do you use can you share its import statement

Comment: This one `import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` which comes from `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'`